# El resultado de una consulta jdbc se queda en memoria

Tags: java, webservice, weblogic

Resulta que estoy realizando una consulta sencilla a una tabla por medio de jdbc a través del siguiente método:

```
    public MiprUsuario  consultaxlogin (String login){
    MiprUsuario resultado = new MiprUsuario();
    try {            
        Query query = eman.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM NO_PBS.MIPR_USUARIO_JUNTAS WHERE USUARIO_LOGIN = ?", MiprUsuario.class);            
        query.setParameter(1, login);            
        resultado = (MiprUsuario) query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Error en dao de usuarios: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

El entity manager se crea de la siguiente manera:

```
protected EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("db_font");
protected EntityManager eman = emf.createEntityManager();
private EntityTransaction tx = eman.getTransaction();
```

El proyecto completo se despliga en un servidor weblogic 12c y se expone como webservice... El asunto es que al momento de probar el servicio web llamo al método pasándole un texto equivalente al nombre de usuario, se traen los datos sin problema, sin embargo, si realizo una modificación en el registro desde Db y ejecuto nuevamente el método este sigue trayendo los mismos datos de la primera consulta... Al reiniciar el servidor trae los datos correctos.

La verdad es que soy bien noob y estoy bien perdido con este problema... Tal vez sea un asunto del servidor.

Comment: Prueba inicializando de nuevo la variable

Comment: ¿Donde realizas el cierre de la conexión a la BD? Adicional, la forma en que construyes la query parece propensa a ataques de sql injection

Comment: Busca en el jdbc pool de weblogic la caché de sentencias. Y como han sugierido, trata de cerrar las conexiones a BBDD.